# foreach() how to get value of every textbox in that "group" of inputs

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Right now i am trying to make a customer management system, where i can add multiple customers at the same time.

I have a javascript script which allows me to add new rows of information that i can fill in, about customers, but my problem here is that how do i get all the information, separately for every row.

A html example is this:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="lastname[]" />
<input type="text" name="dob[]" />
<hr>
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="lastname[]" />
<input type="text" name="dob[]" />
```

And this can keep on going for ever, until i dont need more fields.

As i need to enter the information to the database individually for each row, i need a script to automatically take those 3 fields, and put in into a mysql command like this

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO customers (name, lastname, dob) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $lastname . "', '" . $dob . "'");
```

and this it needs to do for every row there is.

I have tried to make something with foreach and nested foreach, but i can't seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show, what you have tried so far (=code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change the name of your inputs like

```
<input type="text" name="data[n][name]" />
<input type="text" name="data[n][lastname]" />
<input type="text" name="data[n][dob]" />
```

where `n` start from 0 to whatever. Then you can use a foreach:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {
    // $data['name']
    // $data['lastname']
    // $data['dob']
}
```

Comment: I added this to a javascript where it automatically counts up, and it works perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared statement instead of concatenating strings. Then use a `foreach` loop that gets the corresponding values from each `$_POST` parameter array.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO customers (name, lastname, dob) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $name, $lastname, $dob);

foreach ($_POST['name'] as $i => $name) {
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'][$i];
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
}
```